# Open Graph Tutorial - Get New Action Code Snippet

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm sorry if the question is a newbie question but I can't seem to find the answer.

I'm following the Open Graph Tutorial. I am in Step 4: Publish Actions. I am at the chapter Publish an Action. The tutorial says:

*"The Open Graph Dashboard page has a 'Get Code' link next to your action. This contains curl code snippets that you can copy into terminal and run directly."*

Here is my curl code snippet:

```
curl -F 'access_token=(myaccess_token_replaced)' \
     -F 'podcast=http://samples.ogp.me/(code replaced)' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/myapname:listen'
```

What do I do with this code snippet? I entered the code snippet in my PuTTY terminal and all I got back was a response:

```
{"id":"341348384144"} (not the actual id number)
```

I thought it would return more code than that. The tutorial has a new block of code in the example.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function postCook()
{
    FB.api('/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook' + 
                '?recipe=http://example.com/cookie.html','post',
                function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

Do I hand code this and just replace the response.id with the id code that I got back from the curl code snippet?

Please / Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ID is the identifier for the action you just posted.  It should be unique each time you HTTP post to that url.   I believe the CURL code was to be for you to play with just like the Graph API explorer tool is used to play with the graph API.  The javascript code you posted above is another example of how to accomplish the same thing that the CURL code did (at least it appear that way to me)